# Skywriter Hat and Google AIY Kit possible?

Tags: gpio

I looked at https://de.pinout.xyz/pinout/skywriter_hat and http://de.pinout.xyz/pinout/voice_hat . Both need pin 11 and 13. Is there any way I can use both at the same time. Can I redirect the skywriter hat to some other pins?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can just connect those two pins of skywriter hat to other gpio pins using jumper wires im not sure how it connects to the pi but you can try that

Comment: thanks, but then i would need to know how to redirect them in the code they provide which I don't. also I think it works with i2c and it might without any redirection at all just by stagging the hats...